# Graphics card keeps cache upon reboot

Tags: windows-7, linux, ubuntu, resolution, graphics

I have a dual monitor system with my computer dualbooting ubuntu and windows 7. Whenever i boot into ubuntu it doesnt remember my resolution setting. For some odd reason when switch resolutions on the ubuntu side, I will see a semi corrupt (i can still make it out) image of whatever i was looking at on windows 7 (where i just rebooted from). Why is this happening? Does the gfx card have cache and is it just displaying it?

I did not install the propriety drivers on ubuntu.

Comment: can you provide us with specs on your machine & cpu.

Comment: core2duo e3400 @ 3.00 ghz, nvidia gt 630, 6 gig ram. It was also booted off usb hdd (dont think that fact particularly matters)...this is a reboot not a full shutdown